# Can't get "Action.Submit" to work in schema v1.4 for Azure bot framework

Tags: javascript, json, azure, botframework

Very new to Azure bot framework.
The complier does not seem to like this code, not sure why.
I'm running v1.4 of the schema and when i try to use the "ActionSet" type to nest my "Action.Execute" action the complier yells at me.
anyone seen this before?
Please and thank you..

![image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4jyI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You can ignore the compiler. Adaptive card versioning is *channel dependent*, not bot framework dependent.

For example, if you are testing an adaptive card 1.4 on the Emulator it won't render, because the Emulator only supports up to version 1.3. However, without changing any code and deploying the adaptive card on MS Teams, it will work because MS Teams channel supports up to version 1.4.

Test out your json on the adaptive card designer (https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) first to see how it renders on MS Teams (can you select the host app there). The Adaptive Card designer will show you warnings based on what app supports what version. For example if you choose MS Teams as the host app on the designer but set the adaptive card version to 1.5, it will warn you saying MS Teams currently only supports up to version 1.4. Therefore testing out your json on the designer and then templating your adaptive card accordingly in your code will help you debug and deploy adaptive card 1.4 templates for channels that support it.

Verify that the host app you want to deploy your bot to supports adaptive card 1.4.